# How To Add Row,Column and Merge row at the Runtime on GridView According to Data Property Provided On Sqldatareader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am working on ASP.NET3.5. I have to present mention Dataset on GridView under the given format at the run time.

**Datset**

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME            2011-01-01_FLAG     2011-01-01_INDATE   2011-01-01_INTIME   2011-01-01_INSTATUS 2011-01-01_OUTDATE  2011-01-01_OUTTIME  2011-01-01_OUTSTATUS
1        Mr Netra Thapa         ATTN             2011-01-03          09:01:59             EI                 2011-01-03          18:0:15            
2        Mr Luja Manadhar       ATTN             2011-01-03          10:15:00             LI                 2011-01-03          17:0:15               EO  
3        Mr Kushal Joshi        ABS              NULL                NULL                   NULL            NULL                      NULL             NULL
4        Mr Prakash Gobhaju     ATTN             2011-01-03          09:00:15               NULL             2011-01-03         18:30:15               EO
```

**I Have to present This Data using  DataGird on the bellow format**

```
Employee Id Employee Name                     01-01-2011    
                                     In Time        Out Time         Remarks    
1             Mr Netra Thapa        09:01:59       18:0:15          Earlry In
2             Mr Luja Manadhar      10:15:00       17:0:15          Late In , Early Out
3             Mr Kushal Joshi                        Absent
4             Mr Prakash Gobhaju        09:00:15       18:30:15         Late Out
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to format your dataset in two ways:

1. Set description of the header rows. Use the "HeaderText" property of your fields in your columns for that purpose.
2. Format / override some information:

For simple modifications, you may use the TemplateFields, as described for example here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/GridViewExamplesForASPNET2009162008055815AM/GridViewExamplesForASPNET20.aspx

For more complex ones I recommend using the RowDataBound event handler, as described on the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First bring remarks field in your dataset according to time difference.
You can use case in SQL Server. 
In gridview columns take a templated field and make structure according to your need.